# 404 Not Found: Something wrong

Tags: jsp, servlets, http-status-code-404

I typed localhost:8080/projectName/Myservlet into address bar of my browser, and got 404 error.

Myservlet.java

```
package com.test.servlet;  

import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Myservlet extends HttpServlet{
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException{
        PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();

        out.println("<html><body><h1>Today</h1>Myservlet</body></html>");
    }
}
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
    <Servlet>
        <Servlet-name>servlet</Servlet-name>
        <Servlet-class>Myservlet</Servlet-class>
    </Servlet>

    <Servlet-mapping>
        <Servlet-name>servlet</Servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/Myservlet</url-pattern>
    </Servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: if you previously set up a local server, you may be running on port 8081. Make sure you verify this- but just for GP what kind of server is it? are you using jersey? give us more info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in web.xml you are not defining the full path of the class:

```
<Servlet>
    <Servlet-name>servlet</Servlet-name>
    <Servlet-class>com.test.servlet.Myservlet</Servlet-class>
</Servlet>

<Servlet-mapping>
    <Servlet-name>servlet</Servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/Myservlet</url-pattern>
</Servlet-mapping>
```

`com.test.servlet` is the package name of Myservlet class. Please use full path to classes.